# What is the best way to stop flickering of error message in angular when it is displayed based on the flag retrieved via action stream?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, rxjs, ngrx

This is what I have been trying to show the data in the template file. But I can see the sudden appearance and disappearance of the error message during the initial page load. It is because the flag is getting false and then becoming true. Is there any way to fetch the ultimate value to stop this visually disturbing behaviour in the UI?

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="!(flag$|async)">
      <p>Sample message</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you please set the flag value default true?

Comment: still, it will be overwritten when the flag will be fetched via ngRx selector and the same behaviour will repeat I guess.

Comment: Can you please set your flag as default value (true or false) in your component and remove `| async` part. If you can also implement this in Stackblizt, I can help better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this approach from all of my components, I have defined modal in my app's root level which is,

**@app.component.html**

```
<!-- ERROR MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="errorModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Message</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-warning">
                            An error occured.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- SUCCESS MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="successModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Message</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <b><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-square-o"></i> Operation completed succesfully.</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And showing related modal depending my service response,

**@some.component.ts**

```
  /* D E L E T E   D O C U M E N T */
  deleteDocument(recordId: string) {
      this.deleteDocumentSubscription = this.getLetterOfGuaranteeService.deleteScannedDocument(recordId).subscribe(
        succ => {
          $("#successModal").modal('show'); //show success modal
        },
        error => {
          console.log("no image found");
          $("#errorModal").modal('show'); //show error modal
        });
    
  }
```

Note that, you can also make this as reusable component so it means that you can also pass variable into message boxes/modals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and welcome. But I think my problem is a little different. Subsequent values of different kinds in quick succession causing the flicker problem in the template for me. The value is fetched via the ngRx selector. Do we have any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

RxJS has an operator designed to deal with this problem. Though, in this case, you may be fixing the symptoms without addressing the underlying problem. I'm not sure why your page load is setting this flag so many times.

Even so, here's one way to address the issue:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="!(flag$|async)">
      <p>Sample message</p>
</ng-template>
```

Go into your TS file and modify flag$ like this:

```
flag$ = flag$.pipe(
  debounceTimer(100)
);
```

This will turn flag$ into a stream that that only emits the most recent value once the stream has stopped emitting for at least 100 milliseconds.